# How do I include flow-tools in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, include, netflow

In our C++ program we want to process NetFlow data. The only tool for doing this that we've found is [flow-tools](http://www.splintered.net/sw/flow-tools/), which we've installed and are running perfectly from the command line (Linux).

flow-tools is written in c, therefore we thought it might be possible to use it as a library in a c++ program, but we have no idea how to do this.

The gzip for flow-tools, ftp://ftp.eng.oar.net/pub/flow-tools/flow-tools-0.66.tar.gz, includes the c-source of the files, and the dependencies are in the lib-folder.

Is it at all possible to do this, and how? Might there be an alternative to flow-tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It claims to be a library providing an API, so I expect it *is* possible, and even intended.

If you want to use it, you'll need to build the library, link it to your app, and use the documentation (including the source of the included commandline tools, which use that library) to figure out how to use the API.

---

OK, so my current understanding is that the headers and libraries are installed on your system, and you're using Debian package management.

First, you need to know where the libraries and headers files are, so you can tell your build system where to find them: try

```
$ dpkg-query -L flow-tools
```

it should give you the directories in which the flow tools headers and libs are installed.

So, next step is to make those headers and libraries available to your build system: if they're in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`, you can skip the paths. For example if you're building with `make`, you can add something like

```
FLOW_TOOLS_INC = <directory containing .h files>
FLOW_TOOLS_LIB = <directory containing .a file(s)>
CXXFLAGS += -I$(FLOW_TOOLS_INC) -L$(FLOW_TOOLS_LIB)
```

you'll need to add the specific library as well

```
CXXFLAGS += -lft
```

Now (as *zr.* said) you need to bring the API declaration into your source code and start writing against it, like so:

```
extern "C" {             // it is a C library, and we're building C++ (right?)
#include <flow-tools.h>  // or whatever the file name is
}
```

For more concrete details of how to use the library once you're building against it, see the documentation and the source for the command-line utils that ship with it (`apt-get source flow-tools` should get this, or just use the tarball you linked).

For more concrete details of how to configure your build system, see *its* documentation, or ask another question and actually say what it is.

Comment: But it's already installed on my machine using sudo apt-get install flow-tools, shouldn't it be available already?

Comment: You didn't mention that, you described a tarball containing the source! Yes, if you installed the package, the lib and related command-line tools (and documentation) are probably available already.  So, what's the question?

Comment: How would I go about including this? Following the method mentioned by zr. leads to a "No such file or directory"-error thrown when trying to compile. Searching the entire drive for the header-file gives no results, so I don't know exactly what the package I installed contained, except for that it works from the command line, and yes, the documentation is there also. I'm currently trying to install the tarball to see if it will provide me with the header file.

Comment: Probably the `flow-tools` package is _just_ the command-line tools? See if there is a `flow-tools-dev` package or similar, or just search aptitude (or package manager of choice) for flow-tools and see what you're missing. (NB if that is the case, just replace `flow-tools` with `flow-tools-dev` in my edit above.)

Comment: Ahh, flow-tools-dev did the trick. Now I know. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you may have an option of using a C library in your C++ code. It is done very similarly to using a C++ library, only difference is that you wrap your declaration with 'extern "C" ':

```
extern "C" {
   #include "c-lib-header.h"
 }

int main() {
 c_func1();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen this, so I guess I should've narrowed down my question a little. Do I need to build the files, or could I place the header-file and it's source files in folders under my project directory?

Comment: Are you asking _how_ to link against a library, or _how_ to manage the package you apparently installed, or what?

Comment: If you install flow-tools-dev, you will have all the pre-built library (*.a) files installed on your system, then all you will need to do is link against them.

Comment: Well, I'm asking both how to link against a library, and also why I apparently can't use the package that I installed in my program.

Comment: @andersem, you haven't said how you've _tried_ to use it, or why that failed. It should certainly be possible and probably trivial. I've added lots of detail, but without knowing where you're stuck, it's a bit speculative.